# Ping in one direction is fine. Ping in the other direction loses 40% - 60%

Tags: linux-networking

- Two Oracle Linux (RHEL-family) VMs running on VMware.
- They both have a single VMXNET3 interface.
- They both have good default routing and DNS entries.
- They're both on the same subnet.
- No host-based firewalls on either host. The VMware team says NSX firewall rules are disabled for both hosts.

Ping host1 -> host2 is fine.

Ping host2 -> host1 shows 40% - 60% packet loss.

I'm out of obvious places to look. Who has some unobvious places to look?

Comment: Any chance there are 2 machines with host1's IP?

Comment: The network team is looking into whether or not *host2*'s IP has been duplicated. No answer so far. (host2 -> host1 fails because responses go to the other IP. Host1 -> host2 succeeds, but how do we know which host is responding?)

Comment: So far, `arp -a` hasn't shown me anything that suggests either host1 or host2 has a duplicate IP address. MAC addresses and IP addresses are lining up.

Comment: To know which is responding, you should be able to look at the MAC of the responses and compare to the expected host

Comment: To check ip address duplication use command: `arping -D -I interface_name -c 4 checked_ip_address ; echo $?` . If it shows 1 duplication exists, if zero - all ok.

Comment: Thanks, @MikhailKhirgiy, that's handy! host1 arping host2 gets an appropriate response. host3 arping host2 gets an appropriate response. host2 arping either of the other two hosts doesn't get a response at all.

I'm also looking at our netmasks. We're normally /22. But, if some external configuration for host2 got set to /24, that would also explain the behavior.